# Independence of 2 discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If I have 2 discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$, and I know their probability mass functions, then how do I show that the $2$ random variables are independent? I know that $\mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)=\mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{P}(Y=y)$, but I don't quite understand what I can do with this to show that they are independent. I think I am just confused by the LHS. What does that even mean? If I have the $2$ pmfs, and I multiply them together to get the RHS of the equation, how would I show that it equals the LHS and are therefore independent?

Comment: the LHS is the probability that $(X=x $ and $ Y=y)$. you want to show that $P(X\in A, Y\in B) = P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$. Note that you can write $ P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$ as a double sum over elements in $A$ and then $B$, and then use your assumption on each term.

Comment: You cannot do this problem with just the probability mass functions of $X$ and $Y$. You need the **joint** probability mass function of $(X, Y)$ as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to calculate $P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x \,\&\, Y=y) = P(\{X=x\} \cap \{Y= y\})  $

Next calculate $P(X=x)\cdot P(Y=y)$

If you get the same result then they are independent, denoted $X \perp \!\!\! \perp Y$.

A few ways to possibly compute $P(X=x, Y =y)$:

Bayes Rule: $P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x\mid Y=y)P(Y=y)$

Addition/Union Rule: $P(\{X = x \} \cup \{Y=y\}) = P(X=x) + P(Y=y) - P(X=x,Y=y)$

Answer (score 0):

Using the intuitive definition of joint probability in terms of conditional probability, we have

$P(X=x, Y=y)=P(X=x|Y=y).P(Y=y)$

$=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$ (given)

Assuming $P(Y=y) \neq 0$ (the trivial case for an impossible event) it implies that $P(X=x|Y=y)=P(X=x)$, which tells us that probability of $X$ does not depend upon the probability of occurence of $Y$, hence they are independent.